# Advatages of using JTA

Tags: hibernate, jta

I am developing a java web application using struts and hibernate. Currently, I am using Hibernate's Transaction for transaction management in hibernate. What is the advantage of using JTA transaction demarcation over Hibernate transaction ? To be more specific, when is it recommended to use JTA ?

Answer (score 5):

It's recommended to use JTA

- when using a Java EE app server, since it provides JTA and connection pooling out of the box, as well as other goodies like a management console, which allows getting statistics, health status, etc. about your transactions
- when you have a distributed transaction, i.e. a transaction that spans multiple transactional resources: two databases, or a database and a JMS broker, etc.

Whether you use JTA or not, I really advise you to use a framework (Spring, EJBs, ...) allowing you to demarcate transactions declaratively, rather than demarcating them with code. This really makes an application more robust and maintainable.